# Gradle Sync Error after migration to Android X

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

Gradle sync is failing with msg

`Error: cause: java/nio/channels/FileChannel$MapMode 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/channels/FileChannel$MapMode`

I have migrated to Android x and updated Android studio to 3.4. That being done I got this error.

Is there any solution to resolve the error? I haven't find anything useful on web yet.